# Responsive menu toggle button align

Tags: css, menu, responsive-design

This is my menu toggle section:

### JS FIDDLE

[jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/mikehudak/xTgmN/) or [external html](http://mike.php5.sk/public/menu/)

Menu look like this

[image: original]

### Question:

What change to **make toggle button** (menu icon) to **align** in `<div class="navigation"></div>` container ? **CSS ONLY**

---

For better imagination here are align text ( left, right, center )

[image: left] [image: right] [image: center]

### HTML:

```
<div class="navigation">
    <div id="slidebox">

                <div id="toggle">
                    <a href="#">&#9776;</a>
                    <a class="top" href="#slidebox">&#9776;</a>
                </div>

                <ul id="box" class="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Homepage</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
</div>
```

### CSS:

```
/* TOGGLE */

#slidebox {
    position: relative;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

#toggle {
    height: 50px;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    background: #0292a8;
    display: none;
    text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { 
    #toggle {
        display: block;
    }
}

#toggle a { 
    position: absolute;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 50px;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: #fff;
}

#box {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { 
    #box {
        display: none;
    }
}

#slidebox:target #box {
    min-height: 100%;
    display: block;
    opacity: 1;
}

#slidebox:target .top { 
    pointer-events: none;
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: In this code you havenot `<div class="navigation"></div>`.

Comment: whole menu is in that div, I added it to code, ... I just narrow problem to toggle section, whole menu is in jsfiddle example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not get your question properly. But it you want it to float left or right. Based on the image you provided, it will be like :

```
#toggle {
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: 0;
width: 50%;
}
```

Give some width,which you like.

Comment: Give it (#toggle) a proper width, then use float left or right according to your wish. No need to change other CSS values.

Comment: remove the float and instead giv margin-left/ margin-right :50%;

Comment: instead of giving 50%, the best way is to give margin-left: auto;
 margin-right: 0;. Will edit my answer.

Comment: can you tell me ? there is some padding after expand menu. padding on RIGHT of page. When you expand menu, scoll to right will appear.

Comment: yeah. Remove the width:100%; you gave to the .menu li a. Then scroll bar will disappear.

Answer (score 0):

From you question what ever i understood.. updated the jsfiddle check out `http://jsfiddle.net`/xTgmN/2/

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you must set `#toggle` css to `display:inline-block;`

```
@media screen and (max-width: 640px) { 
    #toggle {
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

After you can doing anything. Set your width and floating.

```
#toggle {
    width:50px;
    float:right;
}
```

Check out http://jsfiddle.net/xTgmN/3/